# Remove region from address information in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, address, country-regions

How can I remove the region (code is `<!-- ko text: address().region -->`) from the address field, if customer is logged in (see screenshot).

I have already removed `{region}` from the customer address template configuration and disabled region information

[image]

Answer (score -1):

found it in template endor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

Comment: To make this answer useful for future visitors, please also share what you did to remove the region. By the way, changing files directly in `vendor` is something you should never do. In the next Magento update your changes will be lost. If you must override a template, do it in your theme instead